# How to display new item at the top position of the adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to display new data at the top position of an adapter? Here are the coding:-

Sorry just now, I wrongly copy the coding, now I just noticed. Sorry my bad. The issues now is I want to display the latest advertisement at the top of the adapter....

```
mDatabase.child("Advertisement").child(mAuth.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            //iterating through all the values in database
            mChildrenList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Advertisement advertisement = postSnapshot.getValue(Advertisement.class);
                mChildrenList.add(advertisement);
            }
            //Creating adapter
            mAdapter = new AdvertisementAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mChildrenList, "AddAds");

            //Adding adapter to recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            //mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you give the log of the error you got?

Comment: what is a red error? please provide logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
tuitionPackageList.add(0, new TuitionPackage(tuitionPackageList));
```

you get an error because you are instantiating a `TuitionPackage` object with `tuitionPackageList` as a parameter and I believe this is not correct.  
Earlier in the code you made the same instantiation with just:

```
TuitionPackage tuitionPackage = new TuitionPackage();
```

and you added the item to the end of the list.  
Is it this item that you wanted to add at position 0?  
**Edit** change to this:

```
else {
    TuitionPackage tuitionPackage = new TuitionPackage();
    tuitionPackage.setPrice(mPriceView.getText().toString());
    tuitionPackageList.add(0, tuitionPackage);
    mPackageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Comment: It works! But for tuitionPackage. I want the whole advertisement. Which is the latest advertisement added will be at the top position in the adapter...

Comment: You know I don't know exactly how all your code works, but if you want the new item at the top you must insert it at position 0 just like the code i wrote above. Isn't it inserted at the top?

Comment: It is. Alright, I will try first. Can I have you email sir? If anything wrong, it easy for me to ask you...

Comment: Post a comment here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183440/discussion-between-adda-and-forpas).

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, I already paste the code in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

replace last else block with this

```
    TuitionPackage tuitionPackage = new TuitionPackage();
    tuitionPackage.setPrice(mPriceView.getText().toString());
    tuitionPackageList.add(tuitionPackage);
    mPackageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my answer with the help from the above coding to sort the first ads at the top position:-

```
//Iterating through all the values in database
            mChildrenList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Advertisement advertisement = postSnapshot.getValue(Advertisement.class);
                mChildrenList.add(0, advertisement);
            }

            //Creating adapter
            mAdapter = new AdvertisementAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mChildrenList, "AddAds");

            //Adding adapter to recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```